# Print list item in python

Tags: python, list

I use the pipeline in python to translate reviews into the English language using this instruction

```
translated = pipe(reviews['review'][0])
```

And the result was a list:

> [{'translation_text': '“Excellent”. Cleanliness and helpful staff.'}]

I want only this part **'“Excellent”. Cleanliness and helpful staff.'** to be printed.

how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can index into the list and dictionary -- accessing the first element using `[0]`, and accessing the sole value of the dictionary using `['translation_text']`:

```py
translated = pipe(reviews['review'][0])[0]['translation_text']
```